# PHP array as variable for diffent array?

Tags: php

How can I load multiple vars each containing a single path into an array variable?

```
$dir1 = "/path/1/";
$dir2 = "/path/2/";
$dir3 = array($dir1, $dir2);

$directories = array($dir3);
$count = 0;
foreach ($directories as $dir) {
    $files = glob("{$dir}*.gz") ?: array();
    $count += count($files);
}
```

When I print $dir3 I get both paths as an array but I cannot get the $dir3 var for $directories to work. I have tried looking for answers but I am unable to find similar use cases. The documentation on php.net is also unclear to me. I'm still new to PHP and programming in general.

I want to figure out how I can have multiple paths in a single var but still have foreach execute on each path in the var.

Comment: Why not directly `foreach` on `$dir3`? Right now you're making it an array of arrays with `array($dir3)`.

Comment: No need for a loop. Glob is capable of using multiple directories at once separated by comma.

Comment: @Jeto Thanks! That replaced $directories with $dir3 worked. Can you mark this as the answer?

Comment: @MarkusZeller I tried glob("{$dir3}") but that doesn't seem to work. What would be the correct way to use it? Tried multiple vars with a single path as well but no luck (eg: $dir1,$dir2)

Comment: Look at [GLOB_BRACE](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$dir3` already is an array containing your directories.

By doing `$directories = array($dir3);`, you're therefore creating an array of arrays.

So you could simply replace your code with:

```
$dir1 = "/path/1/";
$dir2 = "/path/2/";

$directories = array($dir1, $dir2);  // or $directories = [$dir1, $dir2];

$count = 0;
foreach ($directories as $dir) {
    $files = glob("{$dir}*.gz");
    $count += count($files);
}
```

However, as @MarkusZeller has pointed out, you can also pass a comma separated list of directories directly to [`glob`](https://www.php.net/glob), using the `GLOB_BRACE` flag:

```
$dir1 = "/path/1/";
$dir2 = "/path/2/";

$commaSeparatedDirectories = implode(',', [$dir1, $dir2]);

$count = count(glob("{{$commaSeparatedDirectories}}*.gz", GLOB_BRACE));
```

Comment: Looks much cleaner using `GLOB_BRACE`. Thanks for putting my suggestion in.